# Asp.Net MVC RedirectToAction redirects to wrong Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, redirecttoaction

I am working on a web application for school. I currently have a login form and an index page. On my index page is a submit button which calls this redirection:

```
public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }
```

This should redirect me to Login() in the AccountController (.../Account/Login). But it redirects me to (.../Login) instead, which doesn't exist. Can anyone tell me why the redirection doesn't open the right controller?

Here is my Login() function in the AccountController:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And my routing options:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: I don't see how that could be happening with this code. Please show more of actual code.

Comment: Are you sure it is hitting the redirection code? How is your login button setup to hit that redirect code?  Follow up to that I suppose, why not have the button link directly to the login page to begin with?

Comment: thanks for the responses. i have abandoned my old project for now and created a new one where i was more careful. problem solved :)